# Oracle SQL - rownum based on column values

Tags: sql, oracle, rownum

I have the following table:

SPARE_PARTS
Columns:

```
ID      LOC     ITEM        TRAN    CREATE_DATE
105534  12005   00123890    79047   04-JUN-21 03.19.26.982000000 PM
105535  12005   00123890    79047   04-JUN-21 03.40.26.982000000 PM
139500  16003   00173892    79047   09-JUL-21 11.14.00.749000000 PM
139501  16003   00173892    79047   09-JUL-21 11.18.00.749000000 PM
```

I need to the result as:

```
105535  12005   00123890    79047   04-JUN-21 03.40.26.982000000 PM
139501  16003   00173892    79047   09-JUL-21 11.18.00.749000000 PM
```

I need the records of distinct items with the maximum create date having the same Tran

If I use the rownum function, it will only bring one item.

Comment: Could you explain what `having the same tran` means in terms of your expected result?  I missed that detail in the proposed solution.  The solution will work with the given data.  But I'm not so sure what you expect when the data involves different tran values.

Comment: It's possible adding tran to the PARTITION BY clause is sufficient.  I just can't tell without that `expected` detail in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use PARTITION BY:

```
WITH xrows AS (
    SELECT t.*
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY create_date DESC) AS n
      FROM spare_parts t
     )
SELECT *
  FROM xrows
 WHERE n = 1
;
```